# Как в phpMyAdmin создать произвольное поле "photobox"сразу для всех постов Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Как в phpMyAdmin создать произвольное поле "photobox"сразу для всех постов Wordpress?
Мысль в чем... Плагины же создают поля при помощи запросов в базу. Так может через консоль phpMyAdmin то же самое можно сделать? Чтобы скрипт не заказывать. Действие все таки одноразовое.

UPDATE:

"Создав ПП оно уже и так доступно для всех постов" -  если руками создавать то дотсупно только для тех постов, где руками создано. А так как постов несколько тысяч, то сами понимаете...

У меня есть скрипт экспорта/импорта через excel, я им потом буду подправлять значения. Пока поле в БД не создано то нечего подправлять.

По поводу "сломать сайт" - дамп БД решает этот вопрос.

Comment: А зачем? Так никто не делает. При использовании произвольного поля проверяется его существование и выводится некое значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Забудь по "в phpMyAdmin создать". Не лазь базу руками, если нет твёрдого желания поломать сайт. Всё делается только через функции/API ВП. Ида. Создав ПП оно уже и так доступно для всех постов. Если его надо заполнить автоматом, то это другой вопрос.

Comment: Опять набежали эти закрыватели вопросов без дупля в ВП.. Когда это уже закончится? Изыдите, изыдете из этой метки, неучи!!!

Comment: "Создав ПП оно уже и так доступно для всех постов" -  если руками создавать то дотсупно только для тех постов, где руками создано. А так как постов несколько тысяч, то сами понимаете...

У меня есть скрипт экспорта/импорта через excel, я им потом буду подправлять значения. Пока поле в БД не создано то нечего подправлять.

По поводу "сломать сайт" - дамп БД решает этот вопрос.

Мысль в чем... Плагины же создают поля при помощи запросов в базу. Так может через консоль phpMyAdmin то же самое можно сделать? Чтобы скрипт не заказывать. Действие все таки одноразовое.

Comment: >то дотсупно только для тех постов, где руками создано. ...... Нет. Доступно для ВСЕХ. > дамп БД решает этот вопрос...  Наивный.. Но это от не опытности. >Плагины же создают поля при помощи запросов в базу. .... Правильные плагины не лезут напрямую в базу, а используют АПИ.

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как устроено произвольное поле. Это не поле в таблице wp_posts. Это отдельная запись в таблице wp_postmeta. В записи есть поля: id записи, id поста, имя поля, значение поля. Теперь вы понимаете, что совершенно не нужно создавать 10 тысяч пустых записей в таблице wp_postmeta?